# Why there exist error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined if add async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, optimization, pagespeed

My index like this :

```
...
<html >

<head>
    ...
    <script src="/scripts/myapp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/myapp-themming.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="header-static">
    <div class="page-container">
        <!-- this is call header, navigaton, content, footer -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/assets/script/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ...
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If I test pages speed using gtmetrix. And gtmetrix recommendation for Defer parsing of JavaScript. So I try to add `async` like this :

```
<script src="/scripts/myapp.min.js" async></script>
<script src="/scripts/myapp-themming.min.js" async></script>
```

it showing following error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

If I using `defer`, it make 3 error like this : `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function`, and `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: looks like you load your javascript BEFORE loading jQuery - if you use jQuery in you javascript, you need to load your javascript AFTER loading jquery - it's like trying to drive a car before you get into it

Comment: @Jaromanda X This error occurs when I add async or defer. if I don't use it, there's no error

Comment: @Jaromanda X if I move the tag script under the jquery script, it's the same. there is still an error

Comment: If you include script A that relies on script B, you need to ensure that script B is fully loaded when script A runs. `async` is the opposite of that. https://javascript.info/script-async-defer

Comment: The problem is that `$()` is running before jquery is ready. That's what async is for, to prevent scripts from blocking the page while downloading in parallel. Here is how you can [load and use jquery asynchronously](https://idiallo.com/javascript/async-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors as mentioned above, `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function, and Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`

the first problem can be resolved by adding the following js file on the top before any other js as shown below

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
...
<script src="/scripts/myapp.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/myapp-themming.min.js"></script>
```

Next Error is for `select2`. For resolving this issue,add the following stylesheet and js file after `jquery.min.js`

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js">
```

Comment: Don't use "text-speak" in your answers, please.  Instead of _U have two errors..._, it should be _You have two errors..._

Answer (score 0):

First move the two scripts in the `<body>` into the `<head>` section at the top (above the 3 dots you have added). This is what @Nijin Koderi meant.

The important thing is making sure that jQuery is ABOVE everything else so it is loaded first.

Secondly - you can't just use `async` as mentioned in [the other answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863484/how-can-i-optimize-leverage-browser-catching-and-defer-parsing-of-javascript/57864884#57864884) as you will end up with a race condition.

The reason you get less errors with `async` is purely down to load speed of resources, you will find that with enough loads you will get different errors depending on which scripts download the fastest.

It is much easier while you are learning this to use `defer` (in fact I nearly always use defer unless you are loading megabytes of JS or your site needs JS within milliseconds to work)

To quote the answer I gave

> The easiest way [to defer parsing of JavaScript] is to add defer
>   attribute to each JavaScript request.
>
> For better performance (difficult) I would recommend using async
>   instead as this will start downloading sooner and activate each Script
>   as soon as it is available.
>
> However this often causes issues with 'race conditions' where scripts
>   may load out of order (i.e. if you are using jQuery and another script
>   loads before it that needs jQuery you will get an error).
>
> Try defer first and if performance is good use that.