# Uncaught ReferenceError: notifySuccess is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm stuck in a very funny problem :D. My javasript which send the data from front-end to backend, it's work fine but throw an error like this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: notifySuccess is not defined

Javascript code :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "report-service/submit-job",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
           notifySuccess("job is submitted succesfully");
        },
        error: handlerErr
    });
```

I was suprised when I searching this error on google. Google returns 7 results and none of them like this.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your Jquery URL used for the application?

Comment: What is `notifySuccess`? Did you forget to define a function or include a library?

Comment: you may refer the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965684/why-there-exist-error-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-if-add-async

Comment: I'm sorry but what is Jquery URL ???

Comment: @31piy no, i have define jquery 3 in my html.

Comment: @VuongPhamQuan -- You're using that function without it being defined in the page. That's why you get the error you've mentioned.

Comment: @31piy you're right. You helped me sovle my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should validate the **'script'** `<script>... </script>`, it is not self closing tag!

if that is not the issue then you can use something like this:

```
 var submit = {
  send: function (form_id) {
  var url = $(form_id).attr("action");
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "report-service/submit-job",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
           notifySuccess(data);
        },
        error: handlerErr
    }),

    error: function(data) {
      // Some error message
    }
  });
},
notifySuccess:function (data) {
  this.result_data = data;
   console.log("job is submitted successfully");
  }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks very much, although your answer is not what I want but it help me a lot to solve my problem.

Comment: Great! we never know we will get full answer however SO will help you to go in the right direction. Vote and accept as an answer if you think it is worth.